# PHP and Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Running `php composer.phar` with the latest version gives me:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper in phar:/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php on line 19
```

What's up? Works fine locally, but on a Linux server.

This happens as soon as I try to run any commands or just the file directly. I can't self-update or anything. I've tried redownloading.

Comment: Are there any differences in the `php.ini` files on each machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely you have `apc.enable_cli` set to 1, you can check with `php -i | grep apc`.

Another way to check everything is fine to run composer is running the installer in check-only mode:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check
```

APC completely breaks down with PHARs (at least in CLI mode), and it does not provide any caching anyway in CLI since every process is independent, so disabling it makes sense, the flag is just there for debugging purposes AFAIK.